# ExtJS Ajax call not working

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

I am trying to create add panels inside a panel, based upon the count returned by php file. However, I am stumbled at how to use the returned JSON data. Also, I do not see the Ajax call kicking off when I inspect using firebug. My code is as below:

App.js

```
  var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',({
            proxy: {
                type:'ajax',
                  url:'data.php',
                  reader: {
                type : 'json',    
                id: 'Completion_ID',  
                root: "myInventory",
                fields:
                        [{name: 'PMNumber', type: 'int', mapping: 'PMNumber'},
                        ]
                    }
           }

           })
        );

Ext.onReady(function() 
{

ds.load();

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.getElementById('aa'),
    title: 'Marks Entry',
    height: 500,
    width: 880,
    bodyStyle:'padding:15px 15px 15px 15px',
    layout: {
            type: 'table',
            //3 by 3 Grid
            columns: parseInt([{ dataIndex: 'PMNumber'}])
        },
     items: [{ 
             // Blank Panels so html is ''
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010001 &nbsp;' 
        },{
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010002  &nbsp;'

        },{
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010003  &nbsp;' 
        },{
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010004' 
        },
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010005' 
        },
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010006' 
        },
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010007' 
        },
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010008' 
        },
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html: '2003010009'
        },
        ],    
});
});
```

data.php

```
<?php
//connection String
$con = mysql_connect($myhost, $myuser, $mypass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//Select The database
$bool = mysql_select_db($myDB, $con);
if ($bool === False){
    print "can't find $database";
}
// Gather all pending requests
$query = "SELECT
count(*) AS  PMNumber
FROM marks " ;
$result = mysql_query($query, $con); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }
// Now create the json array to be sent to our datastore
$myData = array('myInventory' => $arr);
echo json_encode($myData);
return; 
exit();
}
else { // If no requests found, we return nothing
$myData = array('myInventory' => '');
echo json_encode($myData);
return; 
exit();
}
?>
```

The JSON data returned by the php file when called independently:

```
{"myInventory":[{"PMNumber":"3"}]}
```

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 50px 20px 0 20px;">
    <div id="aa" style="wdith:900px;height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody any idea where am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please note: `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Comment: Thanks Itachi, I was just testing extJS  with MySQL, so grabbed this example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Ext.data.Store is an object that manages tabular data on behalf of data-bound widgets or other consumers of data.  It abstracts those data consumers away from the details of data acquisition and transformation.

If you want to ask the Store to load data directly (as opposed to binding one or more widgets to it), then you can call its ["load" method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load).

I would strongly suggest you read the [white paper](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data) on this subject, as well as the rest of the ExtJS architectural documentation, before proceeding.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code as per your suggestion and can see the Ajax call happening, however, I am still stuck at how to use the value fetched against PMNumber key in JSON response. Any pointers ?

Comment: Try ds.getAt(0).data.PMNumber.  But seriously, you should read about this stuff thoroughly instead of expecting StackOverflow to walk you through every step of the process, because the Ext data features are rich and the way you'll end up wanting to use this stuff is not through imperative calls like this but by wiring your models and views together, as the framework intends.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thank you very much for that beautiful reprimand! I figured out what I was missing!!